# how do I keep single quotes with ^a-zA-Z0-9\?

Tags: hive

I am using something like this to get the text I need. how to extend this to include single quotes if the msg is  'I'hve'  or O'Keefe.

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(msg string,'\n',''),'[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00E0-\u00FC""]+',' ')
```

I have tried \' to keep the  single quote in msg string , but it errors

Comment: What does *"O'Keefe"* mean?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do with single quote. Remove it or what? please provide desired output, what should be donne with O'Keefe for example